# rails find_or_create_by not finding a record that exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using Rails. 4.0.5, Postgres 9.3 and Ruby 2.1.2.  I am running  some code  in a resque task and in the console against the same database (I double checked the db and connection settings)

In a loop I basically execute the following:

`item = ContentItem.create_with(item_params).find_or_create_by(digest: entry.digest)`

for 19 items, it works fine if I rerun the code and it does the find or the create as needed.. But one of them keeps not working . It does not find it, and the create fails  because I get an error on the item

`@messages={:digest=>["has already been taken"]}`

Doing the following on the concerned item and it returns the actual item fine every single call...

`ContentItem.find_by_digest('e9e61c790f0fd63d367f6b2c210cb5d1ed00aefd')`

I am not sure what could cause the behavior.

Field is a string of 40 char, and used as a digest. What am I missing? It is also having an unique index setup.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
found = ContentItem.where(digest: entry.digest).limit(1).first
item = found ? found : ContentItem.create(item_params.merge({digest: entry.digest}))
```

to me, chaning `create_with` and `find_or_create_by` makes no sense

Comment: Let me try that. I am wondering if that's because I have too many insert a once